# How to read all contacts in phone, including google contacts, into an array list?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-contacts

I have tried this where it reads only 4 contacts but does not read all the contacts?

Unable to start activity and getting the below issue:

```
ComponentInfo{com.developer.sparty/com.developer.sparty.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3632)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2270)
```

My `DashboardActivity` code is

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActionBar actionBar;
ArrayList<CONTACTS_DATA> listOfContacts;
public static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 79;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0582CA")));
    //on start default
    actionBar.setTitle(" " + "Chats");
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.show();
    listOfContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ReadContactsAndShowUsers();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
}

public class CONTACTS_DATA {
    public String contact_data_name;
    public String contact_data_phoneNo;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              ReadContactsAndShowUsers();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void ReadContactsAndShowUsers() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if ((cur!=null?cur.getCount():0)>0) {
        while (cur!=null&&cur.moveToNext()) {
            CONTACTS_DATA contacts_data=new CONTACTS_DATA();
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contacts_data.contact_data_name=name;
            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    contacts_data.contact_data_phoneNo=phoneNo;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
            listOfContacts.add(contacts_data);
        }
    }
    if (cur!=null) {
        cur.close();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfContacts.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("CONTACT", listOfContacts.get(i).contact_data_phoneNo);
        Log.d("CONTACT", listOfContacts.get(i).contact_data_name);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these lines in try catch because there are few contacts which do not have phone number associated with them so, you are getting null and crash.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfContacts.size(); i++) {
    try{
          Log.d("CONTACT", listOfContacts.get(i).contact_data_phoneNo);
         } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
      try{
            Log.d("CONTACT", listOfContacts.get(i).contact_data_name);
       } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```